# Interval in which q lies.Let $a_{i}=i+\frac{1}{i}$.Put $p=\frac{1}{20}\sum_{k=1}^{20}a_{k}$and$q=\frac{1}{20}\sum_{k=1}^{20}\frac{1}{a_{k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $$a_{i}=i+\frac{1}{i}$$ for $i=1,2,3...,20$.

Put $$p=\frac{1}{20}\left(a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{20}\right)$$and$$q=\frac{1}{20}\left(\frac{1}{a_{1}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}}+\frac{1}{a_{3}}+...+\frac{1}{a_{20}}\right)$$Then which of the following is correct

$(A)q\in\left(0,\frac{22-p}{21}\right)$

$(B)q\in\left(\frac{22-p}{21},\frac{2(22-p)}{21}\right)$

$(C)q\in\left(\frac{2(22-p)}{21},\frac{2(22-p)}{7}\right)$

$(D)q\in\left(\frac{22-p}{7},\frac{4(22-p)}{21}\right)$

It appears to be question involving A.M>H.M

Answer (score 5):

Forget A.M.>H.M. Write it down on a piece of paper and burn the paper. You don't need anything that sophisticated, nor anything remotely near that.

Let's look at it as follows. $a_i\leqslant i+1$, hence
$$p<{1\over20}\sum_{k=1}^{20}(k+1)={23\over2}$$

Consequently,
$${22-p\over21}>{22-{23\over2}\over21}={1\over2}$$

At the same time $a_i>i$, hence

$$q<{1\over20}\sum_{k=1}^{20}{1\over k}
= {1\over20}\left(1+{1\over2}+\sum_{k=3}^{20}{1\over k}\right)
< {1\over20}\left(1+{1\over2}+{18\over 3}\right)={3\over8}
$$

That makes the answer pretty obvious.